# ios/coredata: Pass object to new VC without first saving to core data

Tags: ios, core-data

In my app there is one view controller that collects information for saving.  When the user clicks done, however, I then give the user the option to save some additional information on a second view controller.

In the first VC, the user creates a new object and saves values to its properties.  I imagine these are in the managed object context.

If the user elects to go to the second view controller, rather than first save, I would like to pass the object to the second controller and do all the saving after the second batch of info is entered.

Is this allowed?

When I use following code and log the object to console from the second VC, it seems to be null.

Thanks for any suggestions.

```
-(void) launchSecondVC {

        UIStoryboard *storyBoard = self.storyboard;

       secondViewController *secondVC =
        [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"alternate"];

        UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: altVC];
        // Do whatever setup you want to here for your title bar, etc
    secondVC.object=_object;
        [self presentModalViewController:nav animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: You should be able to do what you describe. It seems like something must be wrong with the way you are passing or logging the object. Can you share more code? What is _object? What is secondVC.object? How are you logging it?

Comment: You are right.  I created a new managedobject record but forgot to set _object= record.  Once I did this above code worked fine.  Thx!